# compass error when putting in array "SCSS"

Tags: sass, compass

I'm trying to put colors in array

```
    $colors:(
    "facebook": "#3B5998",
    "twitter": "#3CF",
    "google": "#DC4A38",
    "dribbble": "#F26798",
    "skype": "#00AFF0"
);
```

but I got this error :

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "   "facebook"": expected ")", was ": "#3B5998","
```

Comment: I've tried your code and doesn't throw any error to me, it works fine. You can get rid of all the double quotes, it works just fine. Which Sass version are you using?
Maybe try pasting a bit more code before, the error might be before.

Comment: I tried deleting double quotes but it doesn't solve my problem, I am using Scout but don't know where I can get it's version

Comment: OK @amine, can you try pasting a bit more code, especially before what you have pasted already in your question?

Comment: I think it's Scout-App 0.7.1 (2012)

Comment: I tried to open a new scss and add those line in it, but I get the same error : Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "$colors:(facebook": expected ")", was ": #3B5998,"
        on line 1 of C:/wamp/www/alisaid2/assets/sass/testsupp.scss

Comment: however this line works for example : $transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.310, -0.105, 0.430, 1.590);

Comment: yes, looks like Scout doesn't recognise maps, just lists. Your syntax is correct, as far as I can tell. And if there isn't any other code around looks like it's a Scout limit. Can you try with another Sass pre processor?

Comment: Ok thank you for your support, I will try another sass application